# Connect to SQL Server on Linux over the network

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ubuntu, remote

I have setup Microsoft SQL Server on an Ubuntu VM.

I know how to connect to SQL Server on Windows using SSMS -> but unfortunately I can not install SSMS on Ubuntu.

Which leads me to the question at hand of how would I do this from the terminal using sqlcommand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st you need to identify your VM IP address, supposing it is 10.1.1.10

```
sqlcmd -S 10.1.1.10 -U SA -P "YourPassword"
```

Either check connectivity between your host and your VM using

```
ping 10.1.1.10
```

and/or

```
telnet 10.1.1.10 1433
```

Read detailed instructions on Microsoft's link below:

[sqlcmd on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017#connect-locally)

Regarding to web connection, there's no guarantee to be able to connect to the VM via web, that imply many aspects.

Comment: I've include some steps to check the connection.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft SQL Operations Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/faq?view=sql-server-2017), which works on Linux, Mac, *and* Windows, is a feature-rich SQL Server-compatible graphical client.

Assuming your VM has the appropriate ports open in it's firewall, you should be able to connect using the IP address of the VM to connect to the SQL Server.